# libgdx XmlReader children with same tags

Tags: xml, libgdx, xmlreader

```
<level levelid="1">
<chapter>1<chapter>
<mintime>100</mintime>
<maxtime>18000</maxtime>
<totalhexes>7</total>
<target>
    <targettype>2</targettype>
    <targetrestraint>0</targetrestraint>
    <targetcondition>2</targetcondition>
    <targetvalue>1980</targetvalue>
</target>
<target>
    <targettype>1</targettype>
    <targetrestraint>0</targetrestraint>
    <targetcondition>0</targetcondition>
    <targetvalue>3000</targetvalue>
</target>
```

....

When trying to read the different targets. 
Knowing they are 3 targets, I try to cycle through them using the following code:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        XmlReader.Element star = elements
                .getChildByName("target");
        type = star.getInt("ns1:targettype");
        restraint = star.getInt("targetrestraint");
        condition = star.getInt("targetcondition");
        value = star.getInt("targetvalue");
        target.setTargetstar(i, type, restraint, condition, value);     
    }
```

But I always get the values for the first target, doesn't matter if I set star as either one of:

```
XmlReader.Element star = elements.getChildByName("target");
```

or

```
XmlReader.Element star = elements.getChildByNameRecursive("target");
```

What method do I use to read all of the three "target" children?

Answer (score 1):

Use [getChildrenByName()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/XmlReader.Element.html#getChildrenByName%28java.lang.String%29):

```
for (XmlReader.Element target : elements.getChildrenByName("target")) {
    // this should be iterated three times, once for each target
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You always take the first child by using `getChildByName`.
Instead you should use `getChildrenByName`, which gives you all children with this name.
You can easily use the `foreach` loop to cycle through them:

```
for(XmlReader.Element target : elements.getChildrenByName("target")) {
    type = target.getInt("targettype");
    restraint = element.getInt("targetrestraint");
    // Rest of code here
}
```